# Compact-Disk filesystem to handle a million files?

Tags: filesystems, compact-disc

Good day,
I would like to know a compact-disk file system that is able to support millions of files. 
the file systems that i am aware of have a large cluster size (2048) and are not able to store so many files on a CD.
so, what's the best file system to use for such a task?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you hit the limitations if you break up the files in to folders where each folder does not hold more than 65,535 items in it?

Comment: Are you asking how to fit millions of files on a CD, or in a folder?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I am supposed to fit it all in the CD with no directories at all. i just need to find a way to change the file system on the CD so i can decrease the cluster size or something. thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Taegost im trying to fit the on a CD with no directories at all. i tried using different CD filesystems like the ISOs and the UDF but 1 million 1 byte files take up way more space than expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CDs always have 2K sectors](http://disktype.sourceforge.net/doc/ch03s11.html). If you actually need to store millions of files, your best bet will almost certainly be to compress them into a zip file. The [zip64](http://www.artpol-software.com/ziparchive/KB/0610051629.aspx) format allows 2^64-1 files inside an archive, and is natively supported in File Explorer in Windows Vista and above, and by most third-party zip tools.

You could also do a [loopback filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device) if this option is available on the operating systems you are targeting. Several Linux filesystems, including Btrfs, support [tail packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_packing). This may allow you to fit many tiny files on the filesystem.

Fundamentally, though, you are probably trying to answer the wrong question. You shouldn't need to store millions of tiny files on a CD and the fact that you are trying most likely indicates you are taking the wrong approach to your underlying problem.